# SSIS - Data rows have text delimiters - headers do not

Tags: ssis

I'm importing a flat file that has text qualifiers in the data rows but not in the headers -

```
com_nam,lin_ima,com_typ,com_des,fil_fre,add,cit,sta,zip,tre_nam,com_id,fec_ele_yea,ind_ite_con,ind_uni_con,ind_con,ind_ref,par_com_con,oth_com_con,oth_com_ref,can_con,tot_con,tot_con_ref,can_loa,can_loa_rep,oth_loa,oth_loa_rep,tot_loa,tot_loa_rep,tra_fro_oth_aut_com,tra_fro_non_fed_acc,tra_fro_non_fed_lev_acc,tot_non_fed_tra,oth_rec,tot_rec,tot_fed_rec,ope_exp,sha_fed_ope_exp,sha_non_fed_ope_exp,tot_ope_exp,off_to_ope_exp,fed_sha_of_joi_act,non_fed_sha_of_joi_act,non_all_fed_ele_act_par,tot_fed_ele_act,fed_can_com_con,fed_can_con_ref,ind_exp_mad,coo_exp_par,loa_mad,loa_rep_rec,tra_to_oth_aut_com,fun_dis,off_to_fun_exp_pre,exe_leg_acc_dis_pre,off_to_leg_acc_exp_pre,tot_off_to_ope_exp,oth_dis,tot_fed_dis,tot_dis,net_con,net_ope_exp,cas_on_han_beg_of_per,cas_on_han_clo_of_per,deb_owe_by_com,deb_owe_to_com,cov_sta_dat,cov_end_dat,pol_par_com_ref,can_id,cas_on_han_beg_of_yea,cas_on_han_clo_of_yea,exp_sub_to_lim_pri_yea_pre,exp_sub_lim,fed_fun,ite_con_exp_con_com,ite_oth_dis,ite_oth_inc,ite_oth_ref_or_reb,ite_ref_or_reb,oth_fed_ope_exp,sub_con_exp,sub_oth_ref_or_reb,sub_ref_or_reb,tot_com_cos,tot_exp_sub_to_lim_pre,uni_con_exp,uni_oth_dis,uni_oth_inc,uni_oth_ref_or_reb,uni_ref_or_reb,org_tp,
" ADDIVINOLA COMMITTEE; THE","http://www.fec.gov/fecviewer/CandidateCommitteeDetail.do?candidateCommitteeId=C00523332&tabIndex=1","S","P","Q","6 LIBERTY SQUARE #11","BOSTON","MA","02109","ANGELICA ADDIVINOLA","C00523332","2016",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"$103,331.00","$103,331.00","$58,047.00",,"2015-01-01","2015-09-30",,"",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"",
```

I'm not sure how to handle this in the connection manager. Should I just skip the header row and rename the generic field names "Column1" Column2" etc to something more useful in a later step?

Comment: If you are importing to a database then skip headers and map column1, column2,.. to the respective columns in your table.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Implemented and working but took forever with all the columns.